# cron breaks after upgrade 5.69.4 - php 8.2 (deprecated for ${var} in dp.php)

Tags: drupal, cron-job, php8, deprecated

on our staging environment we upgraded to
Drupal 10.2.0 - CiviCRM 5.69.4 - PHP 8.2.15

On the Plesk server for the domain there is a scheduled (cron) job created as:
script path = httpdocs/vendor/bin/cv
arguments = api job.execute --user=cronuser --cwd=/var/www/vhosts/staging.***.**/httpdocs --quiet
Use PHP version = 8.2.15
on run we got errors in website logging:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Deprecated: Using ${var} in strings is
> deprecated, use {$var} instead in
> /var/www/vhosts/staging.x.x/httpdocs/vendor/pear/db/DB.php on line
> 474, referer: https://staging.x.x/admin/reports/status    Apache
> error mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Deprecated: Using ${var} in strings is
> deprecated, use {$var} instead in
> /var/www/vhosts/staging.x.x/httpdocs/vendor/pear/db/DB.php on line
> 547, referer: https://staging.x.x/admin/reports/status    Apache
> error mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Deprecated: Using ${var} in strings is
> deprecated, use {$var} instead in
> /var/www/vhosts/staging.x.x/httpdocs/vendor/pear/db/DB.php on line
> 549, referer: https://staging.x.x/admin/reports/status    Apache
> error mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Deprecated: Using ${var} in strings is
> deprecated, use {$var} instead in
> /var/www/vhosts/staging.x.x/httpdocs/vendor/pear/db/DB.php on line
> 552, referer: https://staging.x.x/admin/reports/status    Apache
> error

As a workarround I tried decreasing the Jobs PHP version to 8.1.27, but this results in:
PHP Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.2.0"

Task "httpdocs/vendor/bin/cv" completed with error in 0 seconds, output:

> PHP Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your
> Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.2.0". You are
> running 8.1.27. in
> /var/www/vhosts/staging.x.x/httpdocs/vendor/composer/platform_check.php
> on line 28 Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform:
> Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.2.0". You are
> running 8.1.27. in
> /var/www/vhosts/staging.x.x/httpdocs/vendor/composer/platform_check.php
> on line 28

Answer (score 2):

The `{$var}` thing is fixed in civi 5.71 but is unimportant. The important line is `Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.2.0". You are running 8.1.27`

You have something in your composer.json or installed that requires php 8.2 but you're using 8.1.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But to my regret I asked the question with a wrong place of the log parts.
The site is running with PHP 8.2.15, using that version i get those deprecation errors. As a workarround I've tried to run the cron task against a lower PHP version. But this result in the Compose-PHP version mismatch. I edited my text to ask the question more correctly. best regards

Comment: I don't think anything's changed though. The `$var` warning isn't important. Your install was based on 8.2, so it requires 8.2. Either remove the vendor folder and composer.lock and re-run `composer install` using 8.1 (not recommended), or if you don't like the log warnings then in php.ini change `error_reporting` to `error_reporting = 1`, or try `composer update pear/db:'~1.12.1'`.